# The tree of $SL_2$ over a local field

Tags: graph-theory, trees, p-adic-number-theory, bruhat-tits-theory

I’m studying Chapter II: $\mathbf{SL}_2$ of Serre’s book “Trees”. In paragraph 1, Serre defines the tree of $SL_2$ over a local field $K$. In particular, he considers the set of $\mathcal O$-lattices of $K^2$ (where $\mathcal O=\{x\in K\vert\ \nu(x)\geq 0\}$ is the ring of integers of $(K,\nu)$) modulo the action of $K^{\times}:=K\setminus\{0\}$ by left multiplication. The set of lattice classes such is the set of vertices of a combinatorial graph $X$. 
In $\mathbf{Theorem\ 1}$, he proves that $X$ is a tree: connectedness is clear, while the fact that $X$ simply connected is not well explained. At some point (pag. 70) he says:

> To prove that $X$ is a tree, it now suffices to show that, if $\Lambda_0,\dots,\Lambda _n$, $n\geq 1$ is the sequence of vertices in a path without backtracking m in $X$, then $\Lambda_0\neq \Lambda _n$. In fact we shall show (by induction on n) that $d(\Lambda_0,\Lambda _n)=n$. 
>   From what we have said above, we can find representatives $L_i\in \Lambda _i$ such that $L_{i+1}\subset L_i$ and $l(L_i/L_{i+1})=1$. We have $l(L_0/L_n)=n$ and we want to show $L_n\not\subset L_0\pi$. By induction hypothesis we have $L_{n-1}\not\subset L_0\pi$.
>   The lattices $L_n$ and $L_{n-2}\pi$ are the inverse images of two lines in the $k=\mathcal O/\pi\mathcal O$-plane $L_{n-1}/L_{n-1}\pi$.

I don’t understand what does it mean by $\mathit{lines}$. I thought that, since $L_n\subset L_{n-1}$ and  $L_{n-1}/L_{n-1}\pi\simeq k^2$, $L_n $ is canonically embedded in it; but what about $L_{n-2}\pi$?

Note. I’m assuming $ K$ to be commutative.

Comment: Thank you, I added the missing part. Now it should be clear (for you).

Comment: What is $L_n$ ? Any $\mathcal{O}$-module between $L_{n-1}$ and $\pi L_{n-1}$ ? If $k = \mathbf{F}_p,\pi = p$ then  $L_{n-1}/\pi L_{n-1} \cong \mathbf{F}_p\times \mathbf{F}_p$  so any non-trivial subgroup is $\cong   (a,b)\mathbf{F}_p$ (a line). For other $k$ the same works because the $\mathcal{O}$-module condition implies  $L_{n}/\pi L_{n-1} $ is a $k$-vector space and $L_{n-1}/\pi L_{n-1} $ is $2$-dimensional $k$-vector space, so $L_{n-1} \supsetneq L_n \supsetneq  \pi L_{n-1} $ implies $L_n/ \pi L_{n-1}$ is one-dimensional $k$-vector space (a line)

Comment: @reuns I don’t understand why is $L_n/\pi L_{n-1}$ even defined. Why is $\pi L_{n-1}$ an $\mathcal O$-submodule of $L_n$?

Comment: You didn't specify what hypothesis you have on $L_{n-1},L_n$. What I assumed is some groups $L_{n-1} \supsetneq L_n \supsetneq  \pi L_{n-1}$ and all of them are free rank $2$ sub $\mathcal{O}$-modules of $K^2$. So $L_n/\pi L_{n-1}$ is a quotient of groups. Also $\pi L_{n-1}$ is a sub-$\mathcal{O}$-module of $L_n$ and $L_n/\pi L_{n-1}$ is a quotient of (free) $\mathcal{O}$-modules. So $L_n/\pi L_{n-1}$ is an $\mathcal{O}$-module and since $\pi L_n = 0$ in the quotient it is a $\mathcal{O}/(\pi)$-module